# RowsAdded Event in DataGridView only firing for first 2 rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

Has anyone come across the issue that the `RowsAdded` event only fires twice and then leaves the loop?

I programatically am populating a `DataGridView` and then performing a couple of calculations to give appropriate figures.

My code is below but when run the `DataGridView` pulls and displays all the data but the calculated fields are only done for the first 2 rows.  By using breakpoints this loops through correctly twice but then leaves the 3rd row and others without looping through the `RowsAdded` event.

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext getIsEmployed = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var result = from a in getIsEmployed.writers
                     where a.name == dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString()
                     select a;

        foreach (var b in result)
        {
            if (b.IsEmployed == true)
            {
                int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["articlesPerWeekDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                decimal val2 = val1 * 300;
                decimal hourlyRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hourlyRateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                int contractedEmployedHours = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hoursDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                decimal employedWage = (((hourlyRate * contractedEmployedHours) * 52) / 12);

                decimal employedBonusPerArticle = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["bonusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                decimal maximumEmployedBonus = (((val1 * employedBonusPerArticle) * 52) / 12);

                decimal maximumEmployedLiability = employedWage + maximumEmployedBonus;

                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ExpectedWeeklyWords"].Value = val2;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CostOfContent"].Value = employedWage;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MaximumBonus"].Value = maximumEmployedBonus;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MaximumLiability"].Value = maximumEmployedLiability;
            }
            else
            {
                int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["articlesPerWeekDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                decimal val2 = val1 * 300;
                int basicCost = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["articlesPerWeekDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                int calculatedBasicCost = (((basicCost * 3) * 52) / 12);

                decimal bonusPerArticle = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["bonusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                decimal maximumBonus = (((val1 * bonusPerArticle) * 52) / 12);

                decimal maximumLiability = calculatedBasicCost + maximumBonus;


                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ExpectedWeeklyWords"].Value = val2;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CostOfContent"].Value = calculatedBasicCost;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MaximumBonus"].Value = maximumBonus;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MaximumLiability"].Value = maximumLiability;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work out a workaround but I am still unsure why it happens.  I ended up having to use the RowStateChanged event in DataGridview and perfoming a check to chen the state changes to "Displayed" and then running the calculations.

Code used is below:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {               
        if(e.StateChanged.ToString() == "Displayed")
        {

            DataClasses1DataContext getIsEmployed = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var result = from a in getIsEmployed.writers
                         where a.name == dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString()
                         select a;

            foreach (var b in result)
            {
                if (b.IsEmployed == true)
                {
                    int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["articlesPerWeekDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    decimal val2 = val1 * 300;
                    decimal hourlyRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["hourlyRateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    int contractedEmployedHours = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["hoursDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    decimal employedWage = (((hourlyRate * contractedEmployedHours) * 52) / 12);

                    decimal employedBonusPerArticle = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["bonusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    decimal maximumEmployedBonus = (((val1 * employedBonusPerArticle) * 52) / 12);

                    decimal maximumEmployedLiability = employedWage + maximumEmployedBonus;

                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["ExpectedWeeklyWords"].Value = val2;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["CostOfContent"].Value = employedWage;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["MaximumBonus"].Value = maximumEmployedBonus;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["MaximumLiability"].Value = maximumEmployedLiability;
                }
                else
                {
                    int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["articlesPerWeekDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    decimal val2 = val1 * 300;
                    int basicCost = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["articlesPerWeekDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    int calculatedBasicCost = (((basicCost * 3) * 52) / 12);

                    decimal bonusPerArticle = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["bonusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    decimal maximumBonus = (((val1 * bonusPerArticle) * 52) / 12);

                    decimal maximumLiability = calculatedBasicCost + maximumBonus;


                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["ExpectedWeeklyWords"].Value = val2;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["CostOfContent"].Value = calculatedBasicCost;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["MaximumBonus"].Value = maximumBonus;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["MaximumLiability"].Value = maximumLiability;
                }
            }
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have encountered the same problem in one of our old applications. Actually the problem is "we are using the "**RowsAdded**" event incorrectly. If you read the documentation for **DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs** class, you will see that it can contain information about addition of more than one row.

```
public class DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  //The number of rows that have been added.
  public int RowCount { get; }

  //The index of the first added row.
  public int RowIndex { get; }
}
```

So, you must process **e.RowCount** number of rows starting at index **e.RowIndex** in order to process all the newly added rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
{
   DataGridViewRow _row = m_dgMetadata.Rows[e.RowIndex + i];
   //.. Do whatever you want
}
```