# WinForm not refreshing after datagridview row change

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a Winform that has 2 datagridviews (parent-child relationship) that I fill with data on form load. I then have a textbox that I put a date in and use it to filter the main grid's databindingSource (which appropriately filter the child grid).

Everything was working fine as I developed the form until it seem to not want to refresh the form... portions of the form would simply be white until I actually move the form around on the screen making it repainted. Now that the form is painted I select different rows in the grid with either the mouse or the navigationsource's next/back arrows. The grid again doesn't refresh unless I move the form around the screen again (grab the title bar and move it around).

I have code in the child form's RowPrePaint method which shouldn't affect anything right? That's the only method that could remotely distrupt the form painting.

I'm going to start reversing my steps but I don't think there is anything that's going to make sense.

Does any of this sound familiar?

Comment: You didn't post any code but you can start by commenting out som portion of code and see what is causing the problem.

Comment: A form does not have a RowPrePaint event, a datagridview does and any code in that event could seriously disrupt the normal painting of the form. Why don't  you post that code so we can see if the problem is there or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that I had conflicting code in the DataGridView_RowsAdded and the DataGridView_RowPrePaint. I've also switched from the DataGridView_RowPrePaint to DataGridView_RowStateChanged as suggested here: [RowsAdded Event in DataGridView only firing for first 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695585/rowsadded-event-in-datagridview-only-firing-for-first-2-rows)

Thanks for the suggestions